# Publishoptions recursively creating cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-core, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core application. In `project.json` i have the publish option configured as below

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.development.json",
      "appsettings.staging.json",
      "appsettings.production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
```

I am using the default project template created by vs 2015 for asp.net core web projects. So all the `.cshtml` files are under `Views` folder.

when i execute `dotnet publish -c Development` command dotnet publishes Views under

> C:\MySolutionDir\Src\MyUIProjectDir\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\Views

then i execute the same command again. This time there are cshtml files already exists under `bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\Views` so this time publish command additionally creates the following folder structure

> C:\MySolutionDir\Src\MyUIProjectDir\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\Views

if i execute the command again then it creates

> C:\MySolutionDir\Src\MyUIProjectDir\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\bin\Development\netcoreapp1.0\publish\Views

it basically recursively finds .cshtml files under "MyUIProjectDir" and keep creating deep hierarchy of Views folder.

Also i have other environments, there are folders like

```
 C:\MySolutionDir\Src\MyUIProjectDir\bin\Staging
 C:\MySolutionDir\Src\MyUIProjectDir\bin\Production
```

The publish command also copies cshtml from "Staging" and "Production" into development.

How do i fix this issue so publish command only copies cshtml from 'MyUIProjectDir\Views' folder (but not from bin)

Comment: what if replace "**/ *.cshtml", to "Views"? as **/ * pattern will also look for files into wwwroot folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`**/*` pattern will also look for files into `wwwroot` folder. You have 2 options:

- modify `**/ *.cshtml` pattern to search `.cshtml` only in specific folder, or directly include folders with your `.cshtml` files (`Views` I guess):

  ```
  "publishOptions": {
     "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        ...
     ]
  }
  ```
- exclude from publishing `.cshtml` files, that are located in `wwwroot` folder. Use `exclude` section in `publishOptions`:

  ```
  "publishOptions": {
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot/*.cshtml"
    ]
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As [Set said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117094/publishoptions-recursively-creating-cshtml-files-in-asp-net-core-project#comment67506355_40117094) you should include your `Views` folder because `**` will search everywhere in your solution including the `wwwroot` folder.

Same behavior for your .cshtml files copied from other environment folders because `**` will search recursively starting from the root folder of your project.

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.development.json",
      "appsettings.staging.json",
      "appsettings.production.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to exclude the bin and obj folders explicitly.

```
"publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "Views",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
],
"exclude": [
  "bin",
  "obj"
]  }
```

I also had to delete everthing in **AppData\Local\temp\PublishTemp** folder before publishing. It was still using the old settings for some reason till i deleted everything from the PublishTemp folder.